# Kill the next sexp and its surrounding whitespace

Tags: kill-text

`kill-whole-line` is quite useful as it completely deletes both content and whitespace unlike `kill-line` which only deletes contents in line. But in `lisp-mode`, it is necessary  to keep parens in tact and `kill-whole-line` fails there.

**Update:**

If point is in a buffer like this

```
|(setq foo "bar")
(setq foo1 "bar1")
```

if i kill line, it should become

```
|(setq foo1 "bar1")
```

but not

```
|    
(setq foo1 "bar1")
```

On the other hand, if point is in a buffer like this

```
(defun foo ()
 |(message "foo"))
```

if i kill line, it should become

```
(defun foo ()
 |)
```

How can i kill whole line and keep parens intact?

Comment: Did you try paredit? I'm not using it, but I know it has lots of lisp-specific editing tricks. I also don't think that deleting a line can be implemented very usefully--it's better to delete expressions rather than lines.

Comment: @Drew updated with an example.

Comment: @wvxvw i want to delete expression only, but i want to cleanup white space along with them

Comment: [Paredit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit) would certainly do it, but my normal editing practice is `C-M-k` then `M-SPC` or `M-/` depending on a situation.

Comment: @wvxvw: +1 for `C-M-k` and `M-SPC` or `M-/`. (But I'm not a fan of paredit.)

Comment: @wvxvw By default, `M-/` is `dabbrev-expand`. I didn't understand why you would do `M-/` after `C-M-k`. `M-SPC` makes sense as it is bound it `just-one-space`.

Comment: @kaushalmodi Sorry, wrong slash, it should be ``M-\`` - `delete-horizontal-space`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **@wvxvw** and **@Drew** implied in the comments, I too believe that `kill-sexp` (bound by default to `C-M-k`) is a more appropriate command to use than `kill-whole-line` for the use cases in your examples.

---

For your first example, I would either use

- `C-M-k` followed by `C-k` (to delete the empty line), or
- `kill-whole-line` *(bound to a convenient key if I use it too often)*

That would do the below,

```el
▮(setq foo "bar")        -- C-M-k, C-k -->   (setq foo1 "bar1") 
(setq foo1 "bar1")
```

---

For your second example, just `C-M-k` would suffice.

```el
(defun foo ()            -- C-M-k -->        (defun foo ()  
 ▮(message "foo"))                           ▮)
```

---

What I like about `C-M-k` is that it always "does what I mean" in situations like this,

```el
(defun foo ()            -- C-M-k -->        (defun foo ()
 ▮                                           ▮) 
  ;; some comment 1  
  ;; some comment 2
  (message "foo"))
```

Note that just that one single command removed the extra new line + comments before the sexp.